# Run jquery code depending on screen size

Tags: jquery

I need to run the following code only if the user's screen size is above that of a mobile or tablet device (let's say 724 px). On a smaller screen device, the div id #mobile-logo-scroll should just be set to display all of the time.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function mobileFader($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('#mobile-logo-scroll').slideDown(500);
        } else {
            $('#mobile-logo-scroll').slideUp(500);
        }
    });
});
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

I am not proficient with jquery, and have tried nesting this inside other conditionals, but with no luck.

What's the best way to conditionally run the code based on screen size?

Comment: Check the size of the window inside your `scroll` handler and have the code run only if the window is the size you want. Sure, it'll run every time the user scrolls, but it won't take much to check the window size.

Comment: I don't know width()? http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try using the window object and its attribute ?

I've seen window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight in the console, maybe you could try with that ?

I dunno what you exactly wanna do but something this-ish should do the job :

```
if(window.innerHeight>724){
    /*do stuff*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used `document.documentElement.clientWidth` in a similar way.